# Hidden input fields causing modal form to be invalid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

I have an angular js application in which I have a modal form to capture payment details. I am validating the input fields using angular required attribute as below.

```
<input name="cardNumInput" required type="text" size="20" class="form-control" ng-model="userInput.paymentParams.CardNumber" ng-minlength="13" ng-maxlength="19"/>
```

Certain fields are visible based on user selections. The requirement I have is that only the visible fields be validated with the required attribute. But it looks like even the hidden inputs are being validated. My submit button is enabled only if the whole form is valid. How do I tell angular to not validate the hidden fields. 
http://plnkr.co/edit/8REV5ai52QylxuBbYCrn?p=preview

I also have the problem of not able to indicate the user that my dropdowns are also mandatory - by showing the red border like on input fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't matter for a validation if an input is visible or not. So try use **ngIf** in stead of **ngShow**

**upd**

for the select highlighting you can use the same approach as with inputs (set the class with ngClass directive), but Bootstrap has no error styles for the select element, so you should define your own (or you can just extend it you you are using less)

for example

```
select.has-error{ border: 1px solid #a94442;}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/FMLxDKBkPkuHmtEvzMrL?p=preview